# Customize the camera view in iphone

Tags: iphone, camera

Thanks in advance.
I want to create a view with customizing camera view.Like this[image]

To do this in one view controller I have created the instance of another view controller and in the second viewcontroller i am creating UIImagepickerController like this:

```
-(void)showCamera
{
camController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        camController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    camController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    camController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    camController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    camController.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    camController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(camController.cameraViewTransform, 2.0f, 2.0f);
// Edited
//[self presentModalViewController:camController animated:YES];

}
```

and in the first view controller :

```
cam = [[CamController alloc]init];
cam.view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 300) ;
[cam showCamera];
[self.view addSubview:cam.view];
//Edited
 [self.cam presentModalViewController:self.cam.camController animated:NO];
 [self performSelector:@selector(setFrame) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
 [self.cam.camController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 250)];
```

This is not working actually. Is it correct process. Can any one help me .

Comment: Can you specify the nature of "not working"?

Comment: @Caleb:Thanks for ur response. Not working means it is not displaying anything.

Comment: @sandhya actually i am doing this type of project so you have done this project. please help me

Answer (score 2):

sandhya , UIImagePickerController has has a built in function for this by the property called cameraOverlayView.

You could alloc the view and then have

```cpp
UIImagePicker *camPicker; // alloc camera picker here bla bla bla
CameraView *camview = [[CameraView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraView" bundle:nil];
camPicker.cameraOverlayView = camview.view;
camPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Shai.

Comment: can I modify it by modifying the pixels displayed. like distorting them and all. Like we have in Photobooth in mac?